# Extjs fileupload - fileitem.getName() is empty

Tags: java, extjs

The below is the code for the file upload:

extjs

```
 buttons: [
 {
     buttonAlign: 'left',
     margin:'1 1 4 300',
     text: 'Upload',
     iconCls: 'upload_button',
     width: '30',
     handler : function() {
         if(validateFile()){
        if (loanWiseStockInfopannel.getForm().isValid()) {
     alert('asdf3'+loanWiseStockInfopannel.getForm().submit());
            loanWiseStockInfopannel.getForm().submit({
                url: 'LoanWiseExcelUpload',                 
                method:'POST',
                success: function(response, opts){
                     msgs = 'File Uploaded Successfully';
                     successFunction(msgs);
                     xl_Reading();
                  },failure: function(response, opts) {
                     msgs = 'File Uploaded Failed'; 
                     successFunction(msgs);
                  }
             })
           }
        }



    } 
}]
```

java file

```
        DiskFileUpload diskfileupload = new DiskFileUpload();
        long maxfilesize =1*1024*1024;//1MB         
        System.out.println("Max File size allowed is (in bytes) :: "+maxfilesize);
        diskfileupload.setSizeMax(maxfilesize);
        diskfileupload.setSizeThreshold(4096);

        System.out.println("===> Uploading the file to :: "+FilePaths.UPLD_DEST_DIR_PATH);
        diskfileupload.setRepositoryPath(FilePaths.UPLD_DEST_DIR_PATH);

        List list = diskfileupload.parseRequest(request);
        for(Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            fileitem = (FileItem)iterator.next();
            if(!fileitem.isFormField()){
                if(fileitem.getSize() < 1){
                    //Added by Sowbakia for AppSecIssues-ContentValidation
                    errorflag   = true;
                    errorMsg    = "Not a valid Excel file"; 
                    //Add End
                }
                //throw new Exception("No file was uplaoded");
                String s = fileitem.getName();
                System.out.println(fileitem+"--"+s);
                inputstream = fileitem.getInputStream();
            }
        }
```

The sysout that I get is:

```
Max File size allowed is (in bytes) :: 1048576
===> Uploading the file to :: /usr9/SIR06072/ifms/upld/indent
name=, StoreLocation=/usr9/SIR06072/ifms/upld/indent/upload__4272a855_14b151f83db__7f97_00000098.tmp, size=0bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=importFile--
```

In the place of the name of the file, I receive an empty string. This doesn't allow me to upload the file.
Can anyone please help me out of this?

Comment: I have tried 3 other types of uploading a file, none worked. All the ways, give me an empty string on the `fileitem.getName()`. I think there is a problem in `extjs` part of my code. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

```js
class InnerThread2 {
  private int countDown = 5;

  private Thread t;

  public InnerThread2(String name) {
    t = new Thread(name) {
      public void run() {
        while (true) {
          System.out.println(this);
          if (--countDown == 0)
            return;
          try {
            sleep(10);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        }
      }

      public String toString() {
        return getName() + ": " + countDown;
      }
    };
    t.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want me to add this as an inner class in my method? Can you please explain?